# Testing for a Non-Linear regression in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

How do I test if a non-linear least squares regression best fits a given set of data in R? More specifically I'm interested in getting estimates for a regression like this:
$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1(x_1-a)+u$$

(for the variables $\beta_0$,$\beta_1$ and $a$). How would I code this?

Comment: What does "best fits" mean? What is it being compared with?

Comment: Your specification is linear in parameters. To test for non-linearity, you could estimate another model including a non-linear effect (e.g. Y = b0 + b1.X1 + b2.(X1*X1) + U) and use a log-likelihood ratio to compare the performance of this 2nd model with your first reference model.

Comment: @Glen_b im looking for statistically significant betas. Its being compared to a standard linear regression model without $a$  being subtracted from the $x_1$

Comment: @Umka so just throw in an arbitrary constant and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (as your question seems to say) that you have three parameters to estimate ($\beta_0,\beta_1,a$) then this model is not identifiable.

\begin{eqnarray}
y&=&\beta_0+\beta_1(x_1-a)+u\\
&=&(\beta_0-\beta_1 a)+\beta_1 x_1+u\\
&=&\beta_0^*+\beta_1 x_1+u
\end{eqnarray}

Now consider that there's some best estimate of slope $\hat{\beta}_1$, and a corresponding best intercept $\hat{\beta}_0^*$ (this doesn't rely on how they're estimated - it doesn't matter).

Then in your formulation the intercept (given the slope) has two free parameters ($\beta_0$ and $a$), so that for a given $\hat{\beta}_0^*$ there's an infinite set of pairs ($\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat a$) which will give that best fitting value of intercept. So you simply can't tell which pair it might be -- they will all give identical fits.

As it stands, there's nothing to be done here.